# Camera rolls instead of looking up and down

Tags: unity, camera, mouse

I got a small script from the official Unity forum which is:

```
public class MouseRotationUpDown : MonoBehaviour {
    public float RotationSpeed = 5;

    void Update () 
    {
        transform.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotationSpeed,0, 0 /** Time.deltaTime*/, Space.World);
    }
}
```

This script should rotate (as in looking up and down) the camera, based on my mouse movement. But instead of just rotating the camera over the X axis (up & down) it rotates the camera over all three axis at once.

This is the only script attached right now.

Comment: You're rotating with respect to Space.World. So if your camera's z-axis is pointing along the world x-axis, then what you're applying as a pitch (world x-axist rotation) will be observed as a roll (local z-axis rotation). Does the problem persist if you try Space.Self, or play with different starting orientations for the camera?

Comment: @DMGregory You fixed the issue. I think I should've gone more in depth when reading up on rotation. Didn't know the details about the 4th parameter in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMGregory posted this and I'm just copying his comment to be able to close this question with an answer.

> You're rotating with respect to Space.World. So if your camera's
>   z-axis is pointing along the world x-axis, then what you're applying
>   as a pitch (world x-axist rotation) will be observed as a roll (local
>   z-axis rotation). Does the problem persist if you try Space.Self, or
>   play with different starting orientations for the camera? –  DMGregory

So I changed Space.World to Space.Self and the issue got fixed. Thanks everyone for leading to this answer.